# How to translate and elements position based on scroll of body?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to achieve something like this. In the given link the three phones appear based on the scroll of body and when all the three phones are visible the whole body starts to scroll to display the remaining content.
Here is the example
https://www.mi.com/in/product/redmi-note-12-pro-plus-5g/

I have not tried anything I am completely lost.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the page? From what I can see, the `transform(...)` CSS property is getting dynamically updated by the page's JavaScript.

Comment: yes I have seen and I got the part of transforming the phone. But I am still not able to figure out the part where the background should be stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This is considered a scrolling animation, and there is much complexity that goes into designing one. If you would like to implement something like this yourself, I recommend learning a library that accomplishes the task, like [scroll magic](https://scrollmagic.io/) or [threejs](https://threejs.org/). However, it is possible to do this with vanilla js as well. This is a small demo where you can see how a task like this could be accomplished.

I first create a main area which is several times the height of it's viewport, and the whole page which extends further. I have a box positioned sticky inside the main container, and used translate to move it off screen. Then I added an event listener to the window scrolling, and based off where it scrolls change the rotation and translate css properties, with a little logic to move it back on screen and spin it around. The css transition property animates the changes, and all together it allows me to move a box onto the screen as I scroll down, and if I wanted I could design fine tuned animations this way. Of course, with a library it would be much easier.

Happy coding!

```js
const block = document.querySelector(".block");

window
  .addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  const yPos = window.scrollY;
  block.style.rotate = yPos + "deg";
  const yTranslate = 
    yPos > 300 ?
    Math.max(0, 400 - yPos) :
    400;
  block.style.translate = `0 ${yTranslate}px`;
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: calc(10 * 100dvh);

}
main {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  height: calc(8 * 100dvh);
}

.block {
  position: sticky;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  top: calc(50dvh - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  transition: rotate 0.1s, translate 0.1s;
  rotate: 0;
  translate: 0 400px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Welcome!</h1>
<main>
  <div class="block"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning the library they used in your reference site is [gsap](https://gsap.com/)